# struct sockaddr, do we really need to give addrlen

Tags: c, networking, struct

I'm currently writing a C library that use network structures such as `sockaddr`. 
In my code, I am using this ternary condition to deduce the size of such structure.

```
addrlen = sourceaddr->sa_family == 
          AF_INET ? sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) : sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
```

However, most of the standard unix functions such as `bind` has this kind of signatures:

```
int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

It contains explicit declaration of the address length `addrlen`.

My question is: "Why should I need an explicit indication of the address len in my library if I can deduce it with `sa_family`?"

For instance, the bind call can change to this signature:

```
int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr);
```

And use internally:

```
__bind(sockfd, addr, 
       addr->sa_family == AF_INET ? sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) : sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Backwards compatibility. And if you change the signature of your `bind` function, then you're no longer POSIX compliant (if you strive for that) or compatible with any other `bind` function.

Comment: Ok. It means that previous sockaddr structure did not have the sa_family field? So, what would you advise for a recent library: use or not addrlen? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is linked to socket API history between different operating systems. Each system had its own socket implementation and such API were not standardized among them.

> socklen_t is a strange typedef for the size of a struct sockaddr in
>   accept(), getpeername(), and connect().
>
> The reason for this typedef is that in BSD, those functions took an
>   int*, and the POSIX people screwed it all up when they decided to make
>   such arguments point to an integer of (potentially) another size,
>   under a new typedef.